# Is it correct to end a sentence with a superlative without followed noun?

Tags: superlatives

Is it correct to end a sentence with a superlative without followed noun?

For example: `I am the happiest. He is the fastest.`

If it is not correct why do people widely use to say: "**It is the best**" without any continuous noun later? Is it not correct usage or maybe it is an exception?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is natural and fine. The noun is being [elided.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics))

Generally speaking, these types of sentences would occur with some sort of context to let you know what is being elided.

> Out of all the people I know, I am the happiest (person).
> In the 100-meter race, he is the fastest (runner in the 100-meter race).

Without context, though, the ellipsis will be understood as something like this:

> It is the best (thing in the whole world).