# If someone asks me: "is that clear enough?" can I answer "it is clearest" or it "Is the clearest"?

Tags: superlatives

If someone ask me: "**Is that clear enough?**" (in meaning of "do you understand it clearly"?)

can I answer by choosing one of the both answers or should I use one of them?

> 1) "It is **clearest**" (without a definite article)

or

> 2) "It is **the clearest**" (with a definite article)

I saw some answers here on ELL and it's not clear enough for me for my specific case to conclude about an answer:

- [First related question that I saw on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46923/is-there-always-a-the-before-a-superlative-adjective).
- [Second related question that I saw on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/138701/use-of-the-definite-article-before-superlative-adjectives)

Comment: By *clear*, do you mean *understood* or *transparent*? Meaning *understood* cannot be a superlative.

Comment: I mean to "understand". Now I'll edit the post.

Comment: Neither of them is very fluent, though.  It is (the) clearest what?  It sounds like you're ranking things in order of clearness.  I agree with Paul Childs; in this context we would say *completely clear* or *absolutely clear.*

Answer (score 2):

When "Is that clear enough?" means "Do you understand it clearly?", you can't use *clearest*. Use:

> Yes, it is **very clear** to me.

There are many synonyms you can use in place of *very*. See the examples for [*clear*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/clear).

Though using it as a modifier, you could say:

> That is the **clearest** answer I have heard all day.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Originally my question was about the using of definite article here, but you're saying that I cannot use both of the choices. But this answer confuses me with other answer that says that I can end a sentence with a superlative without followed noun. https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/165341/12430

Comment: The problem is that "clear enough" indicates a "sufficient explanation", not a grading of several explanations (as in my second example).

Comment: But I wanted to tell to the answerer that it's not only clear enough but it's most understood.

Comment: @subtle_sibling If that was your intent, you would say something like *It was the most clearly understood.* However, that exact answer would not be the correct response to the actual question you asked. Your question doesn't indicate that there is more than a single item under consideration. To use *most* you have to be comparing something with something else. A single thing cannot, on its own, be *most*. (Except for certain idiomatic expressions such as *Oh, that's most excellent!* that don't apply here.)

Comment: In normal conversation, "clearest" would not be appropriate.  However, someone might respond to that question with "It is the clearest" if it was a flippant response, mocking the question.